# is there a direct way to get the index of an array element, given the element in perl?

Tags: arrays, perl

is there a direct way to find out the index of an array element,
like for example 
@a=qw(a b c);

how do you get the index of the element b;
i know its 1, but imagine this situation for a large array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that the 'answer' is still 1 when searching for 'b' in:

```
@a = qw(a b b c);
```

then, use module [List::MoreUtils](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?List%3a%3aMoreUtils) and `firstidx` (aka `first_index`):

```
use List::MoreUtils qw{ firstidx };

print firstidx { $_ == 'b' } @a;
```

The only downside to this is that List::MoreUtils is not (AFAICS) a core module - so it has to be installed from CPAN.  At least, the [Perl documentation](http://perldoc.perl.org/index-modules-L.html) doesn't document it.

Comment: @RemotePath: yes, it works without the repetition - that was just checking that you didn't want the last index (there's a function `lastidx` you could use) or the Nth index, or something odd.

Comment: i'm a noob so ,i dont know how to use modules. so you are sure that there is no direct way of obtaining the index using core module only?

Comment: @RandomPath: not without reimplementing the functionality of List::MoreUtils; it wouldn't be in the module if it was in the core.  What's your platform/version of Perl?  If it is ActiveState Perl on Windows, you could use the PPM (PPD?) system to get the module; it is one of the first extensions to load.  Otherwise, configuring CPANPLUS (cpanp) or CPAN (cpan) is fairly straight-forward and well worth the investment of time (not a lot of time) to get it to work.

Comment: yes its ActiveState Perl in windows.. i will install it, i'm still in basics of perl. thanks for helping :)

Answer (score 6):

If you are needing to do this often, you may want a hash (in addition to or instead of the array):

```
my @array = qw(a b c);
my %hash;
@hash{ @array } = 0..$#array;
print $hash{b}; # 1
```

Comment: @RemotePath: $#array is the last index of @array, yes.  $# (without an identifier after it) is something different, and deprecated.

Answer (score 1):

I'm fairly certain there isn't a way if all you had was a reference to it (for instance, `\$a[1]`). But given what you said, you could of course search through the array with a loop for "b", and note what index you were on when you found it.

Comment: ya i can do that, but in hashes you can reverse the hash and find the key based on the value, i was wondering if there is an easy way to do it in arrays